# Service not loading in Jaeger UI after deployment in AWS with same image name

Tags: jaeger, opentracing, jaeger-client-go

Jaeger UI is integrated to trace the logs of spring boot application micro service.
But after deployment (using docker compose up) of new image in AWS with same image name the service is not loading in Jaeger UI. If we push service with new image to docker hub and deploy in AWS again the service will started to load in Jaeger UI. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Jaeger UI is configured in docker compose file like below

```
booking-service:
image: booking/booking-management
container_name: booking-service
ports:
  - "80:8090"
environment:
  - OTEL_SERVICE_NAME=booking-management
  - OTEL_TRACES_EXPORTER=jaeger
  - OTEL_EXPORTER_JAEGER_ENDPOINT=http://jaeger:14250
  - OTEL_EXPORTER_JAEGER_TIMEOUT=40000
networks:
  - booking-management-network
jaeger:
container_name: jaeger
image: jaegertracing/all-in-one:latest
ports:
  - 16686:16686
  - 14250:14250
networks:
  - booking-management-network
```

Integrated 'Jaeger UI'. Spring boot micro service not loading 'Jaeger UI' after deployment new image with same name every time in AWS.While giving new name for service the service is loading in 'Jaeger UI'
It should work after every deployment without change name of image.